# Intellij complains tools.jar not in classpath even though JDK is set up

Tags: java, intellij-idea

In my ubuntu installation the JAVA_HOME is setup properly:

```
ubuntu@SB-Ubuntu:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/shared/jdk1.7.0_79
ubuntu@SB-Ubuntu:~$ which javac
/shared/jdk1.7.0_79/bin/javac
```

And the `tools.jar` is available:

```
ll $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
 -rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 15256650 Apr 10  2015 /shared/jdk1.7.0_79/lib/tools.jar
```

So then why is the following error occurring?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure JAVA_HOME is set for the shell from where you starting IDEA?

Comment: @BhushanBhangale  I am starting Intellij from Ubuntu Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing openjdk-7 via apt-get solved the problem.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

It was not necessary to reboot or even to logout.